# How to know the handler spring controller class and the handler method for the specified HttpServletRequest object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to somehow access the handler method with the reflection in the web filter and get the `requestPattern` value without passing the control to the dispatcher servlet. How can I do this?
I only have for that `HttpServletRequest` object and somehow I can also `@Autowire` there `ApplicationContext` object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have started to look how the DispatcherServlet itself decides which handler method it will give the control and implemented with such a way.
Here is the code:

```
//Initialization in filter constructor
....
final HandlerMapping handlerMappings = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext, HandlerMapping.class, true, false).get("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
....

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       .....
       Method mappingMethod = null;
       try {
            mappingMethod = ((HandlerMethod)handlerMappings.getHandler(request).getHandler()).getMethod();
            RequestMapping requestMapping = mappingMethod.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            final String requestPattern = requestMapping.value();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error("Error getting the mapping bean for the request URL " + request.getRequestURI(), ex);
            return;
       }
       ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the proposal of @Arsen I would suggest to do like this:

```
    try {
        handlerMappings.getHandler(request);
        String requestPattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error getting the mapping bean for the request URL " + request.getRequestURI(), ex);
        return;
    }
```

The `getHandler()` instruction is enoght to trig the spring lookup of the correct controller that will also set the `HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE` attribute, this is usually available in controllers but not in filters.

Be aware that these solutions will waste some resources, cause spring will do the lookup again after that.